# Elementary Java/OOP uncertainties on fields and instances of a class

Tags: java

In a class, you can create fields within them, as int bar in the following example.

```
Class foo{
    int bar;
    foo(int bar){
         bar = bar;
    }

    int getBar() {
         return bar;
    }   

    void setBar(int bar) {
         bar = bar;
    }
}
```

1. Every time I create a new foo object in another class, will that particular object (instance of foo) have a bar property that when changed with the setBar(), only impacts that instance and no other instances?
2. I often see people create getters and setters for properties like bar in the above example. If I feel lazy and I'm just writing code for myself/fun, can I just modify the bar property of any instance of this class by accessing the property `FooInstance1.bar = 22;` instead of having to write a setter and it will have the same effect as in question 1 (just the instance is changed)?
3. How does the Java compiler know what method is a constructor? By the fact that it has the same name as the class? Or by the fact that one does not specify a return value in the function header? Perhaps it doesn't even matter what the compiler thinks is a constructor (no syntactic difference between regular function), it could be just a semantic thing that people use to differentiate the meaning of functions.

EDIT: I'm having a hard time selecting a best answer. I learned something new from everyone. Thanks!

Comment: Your "bar=bar;" statement will have no effect.  I'm pretty sure you want to do "this.bar = bar;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes, but it's not encouraged.  With OO, you're trying to hide information about your instance variables, and provide them access on an as-needed basis.  Also, setting the variable to `public` makes it susceptible to unintentional writes or unprivileged reads.
3. Java recognizes every method by its *signature*.  A signature is composed of its name and it's argument types.  For example, the `main` method has a signature of `main(String[])`.  Constructors are identified by them having the same case-sensitive name as the class.

As an aside, you may want to use `this.bar = bar` instead, or rename your incoming parameter entirely.  Inside of the constructor, the scope of the `bar` variable is local to what was passed in, so your instance level `bar` hasn't been assigned.

Comment: +1 for advice about renaming parameter or using `this` (I've never understood why anybody would choose the same name for a parameter, but it's done all the time).

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes.  That's correct.

2) Yes you can, but the best practice is to use the getter and setter.  That way, the author of the class can write special logic for the property that is assured to be executed on the get or set.  For example, some properties may be calculated on the fly or a notification is sent to listeners when a property is changed.

3) The constructor is the method with no return value and which has the same name as the class.  There can be any number of constructors, but each has to have a unique combination of argument types.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, that is the behavior of member variables, one copy exists for each instance. `static` variables, on the other hand, are class-level variables, one copy shared by all instances.
2. It is a good practice to not expose the members directly and provide getters to access them. Public setters are also generally discouraged to have better control on how the object state gets modified. But, yes, you can modify them directly also once you declare them as public.
3. Yes, constructors are special methods without a return type and the name same as that of the class.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.  That's exactly how it works.
2. Yes, you can do that, but you'll have to declare the field as public:

   `public int bar;`

   Note that this is generally a bad idea and should be avoided.
3. Yes, constructors have the same name as the class and no return type.

**NOTE:**

You should always capitalize the names of classes.

Comment: reg2: isnt the default field access modifier public?

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - The default scope is package-private.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 & Q3 have got good answers. Just have something to add for Q2:

Even if you are writing code for fun, you might be disappointed when you find a couple of functionalities impossible without accessors.

1. You don't want people to change the value of the field but still have read access to it.
2. When you set a field value, you may want to provide some validaton mechanism for it. You can do validation inside setters.
3. If you want to play with Reflection, Serialization, Mock Object, etc, you are expected to have getters and setters.

Just name a few functionalities you might not be able to achieve without accessors. There're many more!